# FBSDK check if user has already authorised app Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I'm setting up log in with facebook, and what I am trying to do is when the user authorises the app for the first time they get segued to a new VC where they select a username.

But if that user logs out and then logs in again with facebook I dont want him to go to the new vc where he selects a username but the Homepage....

Not sure how this is done and haven't been able to find any posts about this apart from how to check if user is logged in....

Thanks in advance to anyone!

Comment: just save state of user locally, like in NSUSerDefaults

Comment: What if the user logs in with facebook from another device?, I need the FBSK to return if he has already authoried the app or not...Lots of apps do this, as if its the first time you login you select a username and password, then if you login again it just takes you striaght to your acc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook isn't going to tell you that you have logged with this app earlier or not.

What you can do, try like below things.

- (1) Successfully login with Facebook
- (2) Get required information from Facebook like - email, id & name.
- (3) Call login API, pass above information in login API and 1 flag "LoggedIn_Facebook"
- (4) If above information coming 1st time on server code via API, then make registration of user, provide appropriate response from API and redirect to homescreen
- (5) Next time when you do above process, server code will consider this user as logged in, provide appropriate response from API and redirect to homescreen.

Comment: Yes I wasn't think of doing it like that 5 minutes ago, was hust hoping there would be an easier solution. I shall be giving it all a go soon, if it work I'll accept

Comment: Great Jack. you can keep local flag in NSUserDefault for autologin, but dont forgot to clean it on logout button.

Comment: Sorted it, was easy +1

Comment: Great, let me if I could help you somewhere .

Comment: Thanks, if you know anything about mysql or uploading to mysql server check my other question out, I have bounty on it for 50 rep